# How to store time greater than 24 Hours in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, sqlexception, node-mysql, editline

I need to create a column (say `idletime`) that will store time value having hours smaller or bigger than 24. When i try to insert such values bigger than 24 (For
example '80:00:00', '129:23:12', etc) , am getting the following error code:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Illegal hour value '80' for java.sql.Time type in value '80:00:00.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:964)
.....
```

I have searched over the Internet and found that the TIME datatype ranges from 00:00:00 to 23:59:59 and  does not reach 24:00:00.

Is there any solution available for my problem? Am executing this insert query within a stored procedure.

Comment: MySQL retrieves and displays TIME values in 'HH:MM:SS' format (or 'HHH:MM:SS' format for large hours values). TIME values may range from '-838:59:59' to '838:59:59' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time.html so even if you can get around your immediate problem you may hit a wall with mysql.

Comment: Sounds like you don’t have an actual MySQL problem, but a Java problem (resp. whoever wrote the tool had it) ... [`java.sql.Time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html) is a generic type, not specific to MySQL, and it restricts the hour portion to 0 to 23.

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL,
 you can store `80:00:00` for `time` datatype.

```
CREATE TABLE `test_time` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

When getting the datetime with QUERY:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP(`time`) FROM `test_time`
```

Output:

```
TIMESTAMP(`time`)    
---------------------
2018-04-22T08:00:00Z
```

What i noticed is when storing in above format, it will +80 hours in stored time.
for example:

if you stored the 80 hours what mysql do is set current time + your input. 
when you want to check what date and time it would be when adding 
`80:00:00` it will show above output, 
Also it can store max `838:59:59` hours.

[**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/601fb4/1)

Comment: Not me BTW but maybe because your answer is wrong see dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time.html

Comment: Much better now :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have a problem from your sql client because of the nature of the exception "**java.sql.SQLException**".

- Go in in a bare console or another sqlclient and try to execute what
  you were trying to do

for example:

```
CREATE Table mytimetable (testtime TIME);

Insert into mytimetable values ('1:1:1'),('080:1:1'),('80:1:1');

select * from mytimetable ;
01:01:01
80:01:01
80:01:01
```

MySQL uses the **'HHH:MM:SS'** format, which is larger than 24 hours.
See [doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/time.html) for more

Comment: Are you talking about a TIME column?

Comment: Yes am talking about the TIME column. I have executed the same query snippet you provided. But, still got the same error.

Comment: Which version of mysql you got? I am on mariadb-10.2.14-winx64

Comment: I am using the following version of mysql:

mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.20, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

Comment: You are right... It got worked in the mysql workbench console. I was getting the error when worked on JetBrains PhpStorm's  mysql console.

Comment: Cool that i what i thought, then let me update my answer to be more acceptable for you

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand the use case, but I'm not sure I would elect to use the *time* datatype for the solution. It might as well be some sort of *int* datatype and named *idle_time_in_seconds*

You might also choose milliseconds if you need to be more exact.